# How does UberEATS know my Uber account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, security

Just downloaded UberEATS for iOS, and on the first screen there is a button with my account name from Uber app and "Continue As xxx@gmail.com". Both apps are from the same company, but with iOS's sandbox environment, how does Uber achieve this? The technique employed needs to be secured as UberEATS is using it to signin to UberEATS. Probably a security token is being passed from Uber app to UberEATS app. But how?

Comment: They would use a keychain group

Comment: may be both apps talk to same end point which gets basic info of your profile ?

Comment: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Comment: @TejaNandamuri in order to do that it would have to know who you are in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS apps can share data via the Keychain (see Keychain Sharing). In this case, they are saving the email and/or password/auth token of the user in the iOS keychain for use with multiple apps. This feature can also be used to restore user credentials, if the app is uninstalled and reinstalled later.

See this Apple [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) on how to enable this feature on your apps. There is also a variety of 3rd party wrappers and helpers to make the API easier to use. The one I have used is [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore)